# Merge a tab print into a data frame with the id that generate the print

Tags: python, pandas

I use a python function which returns a tab format for each i in a data frame. Here is an exemple:

Here is the code I use to generate a tab format for each print:

```
for i in df1['col1']:
    print(u.search(i,frmt="tab",columns=("lineage-id,id,go, go(biological process), go(molecular function),go(cellular component), go-id,reviewed"))
```

and the result is :

```
Taxonomic lineage IDs   Entry   Gene ontology (GO)  Gene ontology (biological process)  Gene ontology (molecular function)  Gene ontology (cellular component)  Gene ontology IDs   Status
    619591  Q8V552  extracellular space [GO:0005615]            extracellular space [GO:0005615]    GO:0005615  unreviewed

Taxonomic lineage IDs   Entry   Gene ontology (GO)  Gene ontology (biological process)  Gene ontology (molecular function)  Gene ontology (cellular component)  Gene ontology IDs   Status
878992  Q8G553  extracellular space [GO:0005616]        golgi   extracellular space [GO:0005615]    GO:0005616  reviewed

Taxonomic lineage IDs   Entry   Gene ontology (GO)  Gene ontology (biological process)  Gene ontology (molecular function)  Gene ontology (cellular component)  Gene ontology IDs   Status
5672    Q89554  extracellular space [GO:0005617]        golgi   extracellular space [GO:0005615]    GO:0005617  reviewed
```

(as you can see there are 8 colnames with some with a space in the name and there are some columns with no informations. As you can also notice, the `Num_009418726.1` did not generate a print because there was no result for this one).

the new colnames are:

```
Taxonomic lineage IDs
Entry
Gene ontology (GO)
Gene ontology (biological process)
Gene ontology (molecular function)
Gene ontology (cellular component)
Gene ontology IDs
Status
```

`df1['col1']` is composed of ids such as:

```
NUm_009468701.1
Num_009418725.1
Num_009418726.1
Num_009429300.1
```

and the idea is to merge these 3 tabs print into the df1 with the corresponding ids in the `df1['col1']`:

and get at the end:

```
col1    Taxonomic lineage IDs   Entry   Gene ontology (GO)  Gene ontology (biological process)  Gene ontology (molecular function)  Gene ontology (cellular component)  Gene ontology IDs   Status
Num_009468701.1 619591  Q8V552  extracellular space [GO:0005615]    NA  NA  extracellular space [GO:0005615]    GO:0005615  unreviewed
Num_009418725.1 878992  Q8G553  extracellular space [GO:0005616]    NA  golgi   extracellular space [GO:0005615]    GO:0005616  reviewed
Num_009418726.1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Num_009429300.1 5672    Q89554  extracellular space [GO:0005617]    NA  golgi   extracellular space [GO:0005615]    GO:0005617  reviewed
```

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could output the function to create a list-of-lists

```
base_list = []
//I am using "..." to indicate "etc." - it is not part of the syntax
for i in df1['col1']:
    if u.search(...):
       base_list.append([i, *u.search(...).split("\t")])
```

And then create a pandas dataframe from this -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(base_list, columns=['col1', ...])
df.set_index('col1', inplace=True)//Set Col1 as your index
df.dropna(how='all')//or you can use how='any' depending on your need
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that sometime the values in df1['col1'] generate nothing because there is no match available for this id (I updated the post to show you an exemple). So I cannot really cat, I have to directly add the part generated at the moment of the print into the df1 by using the id I as a reference to know where to "cat" the 8 rows..

Comment: @chippycentra - Updated the answer